# Accessing Mysql Database from a Machine to another machine using an application

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-studio, server, mysql-connector

So, I basically made a Windows Application using **Visual Studio 2019**, and used **MySQL** as my database to store records.

Now I want to publish that application and send it to a client or try to run it on a different machine, but i think since i have used the localhost as my database connection it wont be able to read or write data on my database from another machine.

So basically I want to know how can i host my mysql database on a machine and access that database from another machine using an application.

I am unable to find any sort of guide to do it online, if someone can guide me or give me a referrence from where I can get information and solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your localhost to be accessed remotely, However, this is not ideal or advised. I will suggest you host your database on one of the virtual or cloud services and access it in your application.
Examples of services like `https://remotemysql.com/` `https://www.db4free.net/` which I advice you use for testing purpose only. You can create your database and they will give you the connection parameters to fill your connection string.
Let me know if is helpful.

Comment: Ok i will surely test it out. But what to do for like a permanent solution? As you said this is for testing purpose. @avalon007

Comment: For a permanent solution, depending on the budget and customer base or need, you can consider any of the cloud `AWS RDS, Azure` or you can try `JawsDB https://www.jawsdb.com/` @SupayanDas